# ¿Como validar si una cadena string ya existe en asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para validar en asp.net si una cadena de texto ingresada es igual a otra. Lo estoy haciendo mediante el método ValidationResult pero no me funciona, les dejo el código.

```
public class ValidacionPlacaExistente
    {
        public static ValidationResult ValidarPlacaExistente(string ValidarPlacaExistente, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            Vehiculo vehiculo = (Vehiculo)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            return ValidarPlacaExistente.Equals(vehiculo.numeroDePlaca.Length)
                ? new ValidationResult("El número de placa ya existe.")
                : ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Comment: vehiculo.numeroDePlaca.Length ??? le estas pasando como parametro la longitud del numero de placa, nunca va a ser igual.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar dos textbox en asp.net existe el control `CompareValidator`

[Validation - CompareValidator](https://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/compare-validator/)

puede validarse del lado del cliente, no tiene porque ser codigo del lado servidor

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox2" />
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" id="cvIguales" controltovalidate="TextBox1" 
   controltocompare="TextBox2" operator="Equal" type="String" errormessage="No son iguales" />
```

como veras es bastante simple y no requiere codigo

[CompareValidator Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator?view=netframework-4.7.2)

En caso de necesitar validar del lado del servidor usarias el control

[Cómo: Validar con respecto a valores de una base de datos para controles de servidor ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/s5z00s5e(v=vs.100).aspx)

El `CustomValidator` permite definir un evento en el servidor para la validacion

Comment: Entiendo, pero la comparación debe ser entre la placa que estoy ingresando y las que ya se encuentran ingresadas en el sistema, para ver si ya existe.?

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando el CustomValidator si es que necesitas un evento en el servidor para realizar la validacion